# How to escape variable in bash for use as content of another script

Tags: wordpress, bash, wp-cli

I'm a creating WordPress `wp-config.php` file using wp-cli.
I'm using the option `--extra-php` to append some php code.

```
if ! [ -f $ROOT_DIR/wp-config.php ]; then
runuser $WEB_USER -s /bin/sh -c "\
wp config create \
  --dbhost=\"${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:-mysql}\" \
  --dbname=\"${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:-wordpress}\" \
  --dbuser=\"${WORDPRESS_DB_USER:-root}\" \
  --dbpass=\"$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD\" \
  --skip-check \
  --extra-php <<PHP
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
  PHP"
fi
```

This is the code I need to be appended to the wp-config.php file:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

But `$_SERVER` is interpreted, and left empty.

```
if (strpos(['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
['HTTPS']='on';
```

I've tried to escape it like: `\$_SERVER`, but I got :

```
if (strpos($_SERVER[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO], https) !== false)
$_SERVER[HTTPS]='on';
```

So I lost all single quotes.

Is there an other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a quoting mess. You cannot embed a here-doc into a quoted string. You might want to use multiple here-docs, and use a [quoted here-doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) where you want to inhibit variable expansion:

```
if ! [ -f "$ROOT_DIR"/wp-config.php ]; then
    # a 'quoted' here-doc
    extraphp=$(cat <<'PHP'
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
        $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
PHP
    )
    # an unquoted here-doc
    wp_command=$(cat <<WP_CONFIG
        wp config create \
            --dbhost="${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:-mysql}" \
            --dbname="${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:-wordpress}" \
            --dbuser="${WORDPRESS_DB_USER:-root}" \
            --dbpass="$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD" \
            --skip-check \
            --extra-php "$extraphp"
WP_CONFIG
    )
    runuser "$WEB_USER" -s /bin/sh -c "$wp_config"
fi
```

Note [the importance of quoting variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells).